Why does the output from Dataframe is different than the Dynamic Frame in AWS Glue?
I'm using a pyspark Dataframe:
Here's an example:
# Dataframe write:

df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("s3://your-bucket/dataframe-output/")

# Dynamicframe write:

from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

dynamic_df = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "dynamic_df")

glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(

    frame=dynamic_df,
    
    connection_type="s3",
    
    connection_options={"path": "s3://your-bucket/dynamicframe-output/"},
    
    format="parquet"

)

Issue: The row count differs between these outputs.

are there null values in data? Are they getting treated differently?
